# how to match several regular expression patterns sequentially in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do matching in the following way for a large multiline text:

I have a few matching patterns:

`$text =~ m#finance(.*?)end#s;`

`$text =~ m#<class>(.*?)</class>#s;`

`$text =~ m#/data(.*?)<end>#s;`

If either one is matched, then print the result `print $1`, and then continue with the rest of the text to match again for the three patterns.

How can I get the printed results in the order they appear in the whole text?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ($text =~ m#(?: finance (.*?) end
                  |   <class> (.*?) </class>
                  |   data    (.*?) </end>
                  )
                 #sgx) {
  print $+;
}
```

ought to do it.

`$+` is the last capturing group that successfully matched.

The `/g` modifier is intended specifically for this kind of usage; it turns the regex into an iterator that, when resumed, continues the match where it left off instead of restarting at the beginning of `$text`.

(And `/x` lets you use arbitrary whitespace, meaning you can make your regexes *readable*.  Or as readable as they get, at least.)

If you need to deal with multiple captures, it becomes a bit harder as you can't use `$+`.  You can, however, test for capturing groups being `define`d:

```
while ($text =~ m#(?: a (.*?) b (.*?) c
                  |   d (.*?) e (.*?) f
                  |   data      (.*?) </end>
                  )
                 #sgx) {
  if (defined $1) {
    # first set matched (don't need to check $2)
  }
  elsif (defined $3) {
    # second set matched
  }
  else {
    # final one matched
  }
}
```

Comment: The branch-reset operator would be useful here: `(?|⋯|⋯|⋯|⋯)`.

Comment: I habitually stick with 5.00503 compatibility because that was the standard Perl at my previous employer.  (Universities....)

Comment: @geekosaur: Just had a question today while working on something here. If I have more than one captures in the matches, for example `while ($text =~ m#(?: finance (.*?) ac (.*?) end
                  |   <class> (.*?) bb (.*?) </class>
                  |   data    (.*?) </end>
                  )
                 #sgx) {`, how to select the matches using `$+`? I tried `$1+`, which does not work. Thanks again.

Comment: That one's a bit harder; `$+` means `the last group that successfully matched`, it is not a modifier and you can't use it with other specifiers.  You *can* test if a capturing group is `defined`. I'll update above for that.